Find Row and Column from value in a matrix
I'm looking to get the row and column names for a specific value in a matrix.
In the below example with the value 5, I want to retrieve "B" & "X"



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D





A
B
C


W
1
2
3


X
4
5
6


Y
7
8
9




What have you tried? This seems very straightforward after a quick search?

Try this has many solutions here: =TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4=5,B1:D1&" & "&A2:A4),2)

I've tried index match to get the row, using the entire matrix as the lookup array but am getting #N/A, i've also tried it as an array formula which didn't work. Google search seemed to just throw up results to do the opposite of what i need (i.e. Index Match Match)

There are many ways: =CONCAT(REPT(B1:D1&" & "&A2:A4,B2:D4=5))
